# Is there a way to enable ligatures globally in Emacs?

Tags: fonts, emacs, ligature

I switch fonts a lot, and most of the ones I use have ligatures. My primary editor is Emacs. Is there some kind of mode to globally enable ligatures for all fonts?

In most of the solutions I have seen, you need to write a function specific to every font, or install a premade mode through one of Emacs' package managers. The problem I have is that each of the functions I found are long. Here is an example of JetBrains Mono:

```
(defconst jetbrains-ligature-mode--ligatures
   '("-->" "//" "/**" "/*" "*/" "<!--" ":=" "->>" "<<-" "->" "<-"
     "<=>" "==" "!=" "<=" ">=" "=:=" "!==" "&&" "||" "..." ".."
     "|||" "///" "&&&" "===" "++" "--" "=>" "|>" "<|" "||>" "<||"
     "|||>" "<|||" ">>" "<<" "::=" "|]" "[|" "{|" "|}"
     "[<" ">]" ":?>" ":?" "/=" "[||]" "!!" "?:" "?." "::"
     "+++" "??" "###" "##" ":::" "####" ".?" "?=" "=!=" "<|>"
     "<:" ":<" ":>" ">:" "<>" "***" ";;" "/==" ".=" ".-" "__"
     "=/=" "<-<" "<<<" ">>>" "<=<" "<<=" "<==" "<==>" "==>" "=>>"
     ">=>" ">>=" ">>-" ">-" "<~>" "-<" "-<<" "=<<" "---" "<-|"
     "<=|" "/\\" "\\/" "|=>" "|~>" "<~~" "<~" "~~" "~~>" "~>"
     "<$>" "<$" "$>" "<+>" "<+" "+>" "<*>" "<*" "*>" "</>" "</" "/>"
     "<->" "..<" "~=" "~-" "-~" "~@" "^=" "-|" "_|_" "|-" "||-"
     "|=" "||=" "#{" "#[" "]#" "#(" "#?" "#_" "#_(" "#:" "#!" "#="
     "&="))

(sort jetbrains-ligature-mode--ligatures (lambda (x y) (> (length x) (length y))))

(dolist (pat jetbrains-ligature-mode--ligatures)
  (set-char-table-range composition-function-table
                      (aref pat 0)
                      (nconc (char-table-range composition-function-table (aref pat 0))
                             (list (vector (regexp-quote pat)
                                           0
                                    'compose-gstring-for-graphic)))))
```

It would be great if you could enable ligatures globally without focusing on a certain font.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something which interrogates the font you are using to discover which of those fancy characters it provides, and then defines ligatures for the supported cases?

Comment: @phils Yes, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: The easiest way for now is Mickey Petersen's https://github.com/mickeynp/ligature.el; you still have to set it up like your example, but only once for all supported fonts.